# Why won't my custom exception work? Java

Tags: java, exception

I tried to do all the eclipse quick fixes but for some reason it still 
gives me an error message when i try to compile it with my test folder

It keeps telling me "`Syntax error on token "InsufficientFundsException", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this` "

and i have no idea what that means, all i need the exception to do is test if my balance becomes negative and if it is negative to spit out how much i am short by.

```
public class BankAccount
{
    // Variables that are private so there is no recounts
    private static int nextID = 100;
    private static int newID() { return nextID++; }
    // Instance variables
    private double balance;
    private int id;
    // Constructors
    public BankAccount()
    {
        this(0);
    }
    public BankAccount(int initBal)
    {
        balance = initBal;
        id      = newID();
    }
    // Instance (non-static) methods
    public double    getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }
    public int    getAccountNumber()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public double getAmount()
    {
        return testAmount;
    }
    public void   deposit (double depositAmount)
    {
        balance += depositAmount;
    }
    public void   withdraw(double amount) throws InsufficientFundsException
    {
        balance -= amount;
        double difference;
        if (balance < balance-amount)
        difference = amount - balance;
        throw new InsufficientFundsException();
        try
        {
            double nbalance = (balance - amount);
        }
        catch (InsufficientFundsException)
        {
            System.out.println("You do not have enough for this transaction , you are short by " + difference);
        }
    }
}
public class InsufficientFundsException extends Exception
{
    public InsufficientFundsException() throws InsufficientFundsException
    {
        throw new InsufficientFundsException();
    }
    public double getAmount()
    {
        return getAmount();
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't added a variable name after the type in your `catch` expression.

Comment: code formatted using http://prettyprinter.de/module.php?name=PrettyPrinter Hopefully it is retained the original content

Comment: Heh, you literally have tried all of Eclipses quick fixes (The exception constructor will infinitely throw exceptions, you're throwing an exception before you reach your try, your try tries to catch it (as well) even though the method throws it, etc etc etc.)

Comment: Aside from the missing variable name in `catch`: you seem confused about how to set up an exception.  The constructor for the exception shouldn't `throw` the exception; there's no need for that.  The `throw  new InsufficientFundsException();` statement will do the throwing you need.  Also, the `getAmount` method in the exception appears to serve no purpose except to throw a `StackOverflow` if anyone is foolish enough to call it.

Comment: Also, the `catch` will never catch the exception, because the `throw` statement that throws the exception isn't inside the `try`.  Also: shouldn't you be checking whether something is `< 0` in order to throw the exception?

Comment: OK, I see, you tried to throw the exception if the `balance` is negative.  First of all, `balance < balance - amount` is the wrong check.  Second, you're missing some curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

The code that is after

`throw new InsufficientFundsException();`

is dead code.

Also other code is simply wrong

E.g.

The `InsufficientFundsException` constructor throws itself.

The `catch (InsufficientFundsException)` is wrong. It needs a variable.

`double nbalance = (balance - amount);` will never throw a `InsufficientFundsException`  exception.

`getAmount()` just recursively calls itself and has no logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have

```
catch (InsufficientFundsException e)
    {
```

Notice the e. You need a variable to "store" the exception in.

After that there are a few more issues you need to fix. When your exception is thrown, it'll instantiate and throw it self again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Copying to answer from comments( Sotirios Delimanolis). Provide variable name in catch ()

```
 catch (InsufficientFundsException someE)
        {
            System.out.println("You do not have enough for this transaction , you are short by " + difference);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly answering the question as asked (which Jayan, DeadChex, and Sotirios Delimanolis have done already), I'll point out that you have a large amount of nonsensical code. Both members of the `InsufficientFundsException` class, for example, do nothing but call themselves unconditionally. If the compiler even accepts that, it'll cause the program to crash as soon as you try to call it. Also, exception constructors look exactly like any other constructor. The exception class should look like this:

```
public class InsufficientFundsException extends Exception {
    double amount;

    public InsufficientFundsException(double amount) {
        super();
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
}
```

One thing that prior answers seem to have missed is that `catch` statements can only catch exceptions that were thrown from within their corresponding `try` blocks, and you don't need to use the `throws` clause if the exception is caught. You also have some logic errors that mean that the `withdraw` method wouldn't do what you meant it to anyway. For it to work, it needs to look like this:

```
public void withdraw(double amount) {
    try {
        if(amount > balance) throw new InsufficientFundsException(amount - balance);
        balance -= amount;
    } catch(InsufficientFundsException e) {
        System.out.println("You do not have enough for this transaction, you are short by $" + e.getAmount());
    }
}
```

Of course, you shouldn't be using exceptions for this at all. Here's a better way to do the same thing:

```
public void withdraw(double amount) {
    if(amount > balance) {
        System.out.println("You do not have enough for this transaction, you are short by $" + (amount - balance));
        return;
    }
    balance -= amount;
}
```